# USA entry and reentry

Tags: visas, usa

I am looking to move to Las Vegas to try and find work but I will initially go just on an ESTA. I realise I can stay in the states for a maximum of 90 days?

If I haven't found a job and need to leave, what countries can I go to before I can come back to Vegas? I was thinking Mexico or Canada for a week?

What time period would I have to be out of the states? Around a week?

Is is possible to get an extension visa?

Comment: I believe Mexico and Canada are excluded to prevent exactly that, see e.g. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/90-day-rule-on-the-us-visa-waiver-program-not-expiring-if-you-go-to-canada?rq=1 The duration issue is addressed in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14051/vwp-question-regarding-re-entry Could you let us know if this answers your question? Searching/navigating the site might also be interesting for you as related issues have been discussed many times in the past.

Comment: Not just Canada and Mexico but also most of the adjacent Caribbean islands.

Comment: Also, getting a work visa might not be trivial or even completely impossible from within the country (that's the way it is in many European countries). I have no idea about the rules in the US (and that's probably off-topic for this site) but you might want to research that as well.

Comment: It's off topic but in general H Visas are issued by the US consulate in the foreign country.  You cannot receive it in the US only an extension for one.  Actually same holds true for all other employment related visas.

Comment: Why is it off topic?

Comment: @user3470 Obtaining Work Visas?

Comment: He wants to ravel to the US. No?

Comment: @user3470 That particular one is a duplicate.  The off-topic was a discussion of the Work Visas.

Comment: Do you know e questions by heart, or how do you inow about duplicates? I have been here for a while and cannot figure this out

Comment: @user3470 Karlson answered this one originally, so he would remember more easily. I just figured visa runs to Canada would be a common idea, vaguely remembered reading about that and used the search function.

Comment: @user3470 There was a lot of discussion awhile back regarding this issue.

Comment: Ok but i was banned for a long time ...

Comment: Ok but i was banned for a long time ...

Comment: It all happened last year; in this question's case.