# When can my mother reenter the USA after a 5-month stay?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, nepali-citizens

My mother has a B1/B2 visa. She is returning to Nepal after a 5-month stay in the USA with me. She wants to come back again after two months. Can she come? What would be the procedure?

Comment: If the visa is still valid, it allows her to come to a U.S. port of entry, where her entry can still be denied by the immigration officer. No procedure except boarding the plane. [Compare "How soon can I re-enter the US after my previous visit?"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14051/how-soon-can-i-re-enter-the-us-after-my-previous-visit)

Comment: How will her employer cope without her for 2 months? Telecommuting? Off season?

Comment: @Harper given that it is illegal to "work" in the US on a B1/B2 visa, I would presume she does not work.

Comment: @Harper, When I read the question I assumed the mother might be older, and retired, and likes to spend time with her child. How you concluded from the question that there is an employer I know not.

Answer (score 6):

There’s a very good chance that if your mother comes back to the USA after just two months following a five month stay, that the immigration control officer will conclude that she has immigration intent and that she shouldn’t be using a B1/B2 non-immigrant visa but instead should return to Nepal and apply for a family immigration visa (which may take years to process).

I assume you want to avoid this.

It’s hard to know exactly what metric the American immigration officers use for flagging B1 entries but one general rule of thumb is to spend more time in your home country than outside of it.

So if she was in the USA for five months, she should try to spend at least five months if not more in Nepal before trying for another reentry.