# Leaving the States on Visa Waiver and coming back

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program, costa-rica

I'm travelling on the ESTA visa waiver, I'm now in the States but would like to go to Costa Rica for a bit (say three weeks) then come back to the States. All will be within my 90 day limit.

Is that allowed?

(I have my onward ticket home.)

Comment: In short: yes, if you leave North America and the Caribbeans within 90 days you are totally OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [90 Day rule on the US Visa Waiver Program not expiring if you go to Canada](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/90-day-rule-on-the-us-visa-waiver-program-not-expiring-if-you-go-to-canada)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, no problem. You  can exit and re-enter during the 90 day limit, and in fact if you leave North America (USA, Canada, Mexico) [the 90 day period resets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/90-day-rule-on-the-us-visa-waiver-program-not-expiring-if-you-go-to-canada?rq=1).

You just need to make sure your ESTA is valid for the entire period as well (they're usually valid for 2 years) and you have evidence of your travel plans and finances are in order.