# Re-entry to USA during time frame of original visa

Tags: visas, usa, uk-citizens

I am a British citizen travelling in the USA for the last 2 months. On  entry to the USA I got a visa valid for 90 days. I am planing to go to Mexico and was wondering if on the return entry to the USA I will get a new via for another 90 days although my original visa will be still valid for 3 weeks at the time of entry back from Mexico.

Comment: Are you sure you got a visa? Or did you get an ESTA and enter under the Visa Waiver Program? About the latter see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/90-day-rule-on-the-us-visa-waiver-program-not-expiring-if-you-go-to-canada?lq=1

Comment: "On entry to the USA I got a visa valid for 90 days." You can't "get a visa" on entry to the U.S. A U.S. visa is for entry to the U.S., and you only get them at U.S. consulates abroad. On entry to the U.S., you get an I-94 (which is now electronic) with a duration of stay.

Answer (score -4):

No problem.
When you exit the country, the visa is cancelled. So hence, it can not be still valid for 3 weeks.

@user102008 any stamp you get on the passport when entering a country is a Visa. Just with minimum decorum.

Comment: Not exactly.  The ESTA 'visa' for the US is valid for 2 years. In addition, a 90 day visa in the US is not cancelled when you exit to Canada or Mexico.  Frustrating exceptions :/

Comment: If it was a visa, then why do they called it the "Visa **Waiver** Program"?  And why do I get the same US entry stamp every time I enter with a Visa that you get when entering under the VWP?

Comment: "any stamp you get on the passport when entering a country is a Visa." Nope. Anything you get when entering the U.S. is NEVER a U.S. visa. Plus, a U.S. visa is to allow you to apply for entry to the U.S.; it has no purpose after entry. So there would be no point in giving you a "visa" upon entry.