# French citizen with Canadian residency to go to the US for the day

Tags: visas, usa, canada, overland, french-citizens

As a French citizen, living in Canada with a permanent residency, what kind of visa do I need if I want to go in the US for a day (or may be a few days)?

I also have a Canadian driving license, it that makes any difference

I would be going by bus or car from Canada, not by plane or boat (apparently the mode of transportation can be of significance).

Comment: related (or even duplicate): [90 Day rule on the US Visa Waiver Program not expiring if you go to Canada](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/90-day-rule-on-the-us-visa-waiver-program-not-expiring-if-you-go-to-canada)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a French citizen, you're part of the Visa Waiver Program (VWP). If you're traveling by land, you do not need to get an ESTA. Having Canadian permanent residence doesn't change the situation.

You will have to fill out an I94W for upon arrival at the border. According to this [FAQ](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1094/~/do-i-need-to-apply-for-esta), you should turn in the I94W form when you leave the U.S. (question 4)

I found this information on the U.S. Customs and Border Protection website in [one](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1132/~/citizen-of-visa-waiver-country,-wants-to-drive-into-u.s.-from-canada-or-mexico,) of the FAQs. Also see question 2 of the previous link.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I was indeed wondering about the ETSA. I am going there this week end, so I will confirm your answer upon return.

Comment: Actually having Canadian residence _does_ change the situation in one relevant way, namely that for a Canadian resident going back to Canada _will_ reset the VWP 90-day clock, which it doesn't for non-residents of Canada.

Comment: Interesting! Can you find an official cite? I've looked but can't find anything. Closest thing was an earlier question here, answered by Doc.

Comment: @mkennedy: Unfortunately I can't find an official source either. The closest I get are earlier (but uncontested) answers here.

Comment: I can confirm the 90-day clock reset with my experience as a Canadian resident, but I am not sure there are authoritative sources (maybe it is due to the NAFTA treaty?)

Comment: The I94W, is it given to you when you get to the border, or do you need to have it with you beforehand?

Comment: You'll get it at the border.

Comment: And it will cost you a couple dollars (6 a couple years ago), which you can pay cash or with a credit card.

Comment: So, I just came back yesterday, and I can confirm that the green I94W is handed and filled at the custom. The guy did mention ETSA, though.

Comment: @Vince: As for the 90 day reset, I am unsure about that. The Canadian agent asked if I was going back to the US in the next 90 days, so I guess she could have removed the green page from my passport and I possibly could have asked for a new one the next time, but it is not entirely certain.

Comment: @njzk2 The reason why the agent asked is that you are not allowed to keep the green page more than 90 days. As long as you have it you are considered in the US, so keeping it longer makes you overstaying. If you plan on coming let's say 10 times to the US within 90 days, you do not need a new one each time, you can keep it and return it the last time you leave the US (so you save time and some money). But failing to return it in the end will be a problem (you can return to any Canadian border agent, i.e. to any Canadian international airport).

Comment: @Vince Thank you for pointing this out. They never mentioned anything about having to return it! How was I supposed to know?!

Comment: Source for supporting the fact that the I-94 **must** be returned at some point. https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/752/~/i-still-have-my-i-94

Comment: @njzk2 I think this was explained in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I am now a Canadian citizen but before that, I was only a national of a Visa Waiver country, with Canadian PR status.

You just bring your passport (and PR card) and make sure to buffer at least an hour if it's a busy crossing for parking your vehicle and filling out the I-94. The PR card isn't actually needed to enter the US, but it's a must to re-enter Canada.

In fact, if the dollar is at parity, I suggest avoiding land crossings during daylight hours until you get your citizenship, because the border line up takes forever and then the I-94 wait on top of that can really ruin your day. I obtained my citizenship while the dollar was worth more than 95 cents US, and I estimate I immediately saved at least 90 minutes per border crossing thanks to my Canadian passport. When I got my Nexus card a year later, I saved at least an extra half hour.

It really sucks that Canadian PRs are treated differently from citizens at the land crossings, even if they are VWP nationals. Canada treats green card holders the same way they treat US passport holders, i.e. you just flash your documentation at the booth and be on your merry way, no need to get out of the car.

With the exchange rate at 81 cents now (as of Jan 2015), I don't think wait times will be what they used to be, so you may not really need 1 hour. But better safe than sorry :)

Comment: Thank you for you answer (and apparently for signing up just for that!)

Comment: "If the dollar is at parity". So not a problem now, then.