# Extending visitor stay in the US

Tags: usa, canada, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, visa-extensions

I have been in the US for 2 months and 20 days. I have 10 days left on my ESTA.

I would like to extend my stay for non-medical reasons. Is there any way to do this? Can I apply for a brand new ESTA while still in my previous ESTA?

Otherwise, can I exit the country to Canada and come back 1 or 2 days later with a new ESTA?
Note: I am not a Canadian citizen.

Comment: The ESTA does not determine how long you can stay. Assuming you are in the US on the VWP (visa waiver program), THAT determines how long you can stay.

Comment: Make sure you read this question and answer: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/90-day-rule-on-the-us-visa-waiver-program-not-expiring-if-you-go-to-canada

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not extend your stay, unless it is some sort of emergency like hospitalization, canceled or delayed flight for more than 24 hours, etc [help.cbp.gov](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1024/~/how-to-extend-my-visa-waiver-program-stay-in-the-u.s.-if-there-is-an-emergency)

ESTA is usually granted for 2 years or until your passport expires (whichever comes earlier), so depending on when yours started it is possible, that you may not have to apply again [help.cbp.gov](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1197/~/esta--general-esta-renewal)

However, one of the conditions for granting the entry is that your travel may not terminate in adjacent country (like Canada, Mexico or any of the Carribean islands) [esta.cbp.dhs.gov](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#vwp3)

Also, note that having an ESTA does not automagically grant you entry - that decision made by the CBP official [www.cbp.gov](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel)

Therefore, you would have to travel some place else then Canada in order not to violate the rules. And you better be prepared to give a good answer to CBP official asking you why you are back so soon.