# Re-entering the US after an extended period in Canada

Tags: usa, canada, us-visa-waiver-program, visa-expiration

I entered the US under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) which allows me to stay in US for 90 days. I moved on to Canada after 30 days and I am now doing an extended stay in the Canada for 80 days. I would like to re-enter the US after my trip of 80 days in Canada. As I understand the VWP will have expired by then.

Since it is an extended trip to Canada (and obviously not crossing the border simply trying to extend my VWP) can I re-enter the US and restart a new VWP?

If not, do I actually have to leave Canada (for a non-neighboring country of the US) within the 90 days of my first entry under the VWP as I am still in the system and Canada doesn't count as a permanent leave from the US?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: A visit to Canada doesn't reset the VWP clock. You need to leave the continent of North America to do that. As far as I can tell there's no period after which a stay in Canada will reset the VWP clock , although a friendly border guard might overlook things if you've been outside the US for 80 days. Don't rely on it!

Comment: Perhaps you can apply for a visa?  It would be worth researching.  I assume visas are available for situations where visitors aren't eligible for the VWP, which you technically wouldn't be upon your return.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @CannonFodder, do we need to leave the continent of North America within the 90 days of the first visit to the US? or is it OK to leave after my stay of 80 days in Canada (which would mean a total of 110 days after my first entry in US). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JimMacKenzie, We tried to get an appointment for a B-2 Visa, but they don't have appointment available for me, since they seem to prioritize Canadians citizens for appointments.

Comment: @skuallpa Take a look at the first answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/does-the-90-days-vwp-rule-expire-if-you-travel-from-the-us-to-canada?rq=1), which covers it pretty well.

Comment: @CannonFodder Thanks. I did read this answer but it doesn't tell me if  I actually have to leave Canada within the 90 days of my first entry under the VWP. If I leave Canada after 110 days from my first entry in US (but having stayed only 30 days in US), am I still able to get a VWP in the future?

Comment: @skuallpa: No, you do not have to leave Canada within 90 days after your US entry. You can stay 30 days in US and then 80 days in Canada, and that will not affect your eligibility for VWP. You were only in the US for 30 days.

Comment: @Greg Actually the time in Canada does affect eligibility for the VWP. If you enter the US under VWP you have 90 days. If you stay 80 days and go to Canada you have met your obligations under the VWP, and you can stay in Canada as long as you're legal __in Canada__. However, staying in Canada does not extend your 90 day deadline under your original VWP entry. If you now stay, say, 60 days in Canada you will be 140 days from your original entry, and ineligible to re-enter the US under the VWP. Fly to anywhere outside the North American continent and you will be eligible again...(more)

Comment: ...the US doesn't care about your time in Canada, except that they won't let you back in more than 90 days after your original entry to the US. This is to prevent people hopping across the border to Canada, Mexico, and a few other places to extend their status. As I already indicated, there doesn't appear to be a period in Canada after which the VWP eligibility is reset.

Comment: @CannonFodder: Yes, that's correct. I was answering the question asked by skuallpa *"If I leave Canada after 110 days from my first entry in US (but having stayed only 30 days in US), am I still able to get a VWP in the future?"*

Comment: @Greg Ah - fair enough

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Everything is now clear. Thanks!